# Random walk, after many many steps, contradictory with law of large number?

Tags: random-walk, ergodic-theory

Assume a random walk, start at 0, step size Gaussian N(1,σ²).

After many many steps (i.e. n=1,000,000), the translation distance is N(n, nσ²).

Here is my confusion: N(n, nσ²) means the probabilty of getting exactly n translation distance is getting lower and lower (nσ²); but according to the law of large number, the chance of getting n translation distance is getting bigger and bigger.

I must be missing something obvious but I am kind of stuck...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This random walk goes to $+\infty$.  How did you apply the law of large numbers?

Comment: The law of large numbers is a statement about expectation, not about probabilities of individual events. In any case, the probability of any specific translation distance is $0$ here in this continuous probability setting.

Comment: According to LLN, (X1+...Xn)/n→μ a.s., when n is large enough. That means, almost surely (probabilty getting closer and closer to 1), (X1+...Xn)/→nμ. Since the expectation size of each step is 1 (μ=1) ，after large n steps, the total distance (X1+...Xn) should converge to n a.s., right?

Comment: It could approach $n\mu+c$ for a non-zero constant $c$.

Answer (score 0):

The law of large numbers states that the sample average of a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables converges* to the expected value of the distribution.

There are two main points you're missing. Firstly, you're considering a sum of a variables. To apply the law of large numbers, you need to divide by n and get a sample average $S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_n {X_n}$, where $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(1, \sigma^2)~\text{i.i.d.}$ So you'll get $S_n \sim \mathcal{N}(1, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$, whose variance approaches zero as $n \to \infty$. Secondly, the law of large numbers is about expectation. If you consider the probability of getting exactly a given translation distance $r$ in your random walk it will always be zero, since the distribution is continuous. This also holds for the sample average for any finite $n$.

* There are different modes of "convergence" depending on the specific form of the law of large numbers (e.g. weak law vs strong law), but that's beyond the point of this answer.

Comment: on the first point: if sample average Sn→1 a.s. (variance→0)，then n·Sn→n, right? On the second point: my mistake! All I was wondering was that for this specific random walk, after large number n steps, the total travel distance should have a high probability of close to n. Right?

Comment: It's true that $E[S_n] = 1$ and $E[nS_n] = n$ (for any $n$). However, while the variance of $S_n$ approaches 0 as $n$ gets bigger, the variance of $n S_n$ does not (indeed, it approaches infinity). Precisely, the variance of $n S_n$ is $n \sigma^2$ and grows just as fast as the mean does (except for a constant factor), which gives an intuition for why your last statement is false.